# Programmatically disable notifications via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

Obviously it would be a bad idea to let a script *enable* notifications, because then instead of asking for permission scripts would just auto-enable them.

However, is it possible to programmatically *disable* notifications? I'm looking to set up a situation to how Slack does theirs (where there is a blue horizontal bar at the top of the screen where you can click it to have the notification prompt come up, or click the X to have it go away).

Ideally the `X` would cause it to disable support for notifications, but I can't find a way to do this. That way the horizontal bar wouldn't come back up next time.

Is the best alternative in this case to just have a `localStorage` implementation that mirrors the answer the users give? That way you can know whether or not to display the horizontal prompt bar at the top?